# Lambda usage to eliminate if

Tags: java, lambda

trying to learn something new about practical lambda usages.

I have this problem:

I have an object that has a List of certain other objects inside. Those objects have MyEnum field. I want to iterate through those objects, get the state of that Enum and then according to that I want to add the object to List1, if a condition is met. If it is not, I want to add the object to List2.

Basically splitting a list to two different lists with a special condition.

I have worked my way through two methods to achieve that, one being an archaic, classical for-each, second being java 8 lambdas, that I'm trying to learn as well.

My codes for both:

```
void groupObjects() {

    for (ListObject listObject : object.getList()) {
        if (MyEnum.STATUS.equals(listObject.getStatus())) {
            otherList.add(listObject);
        } else {
            someOtherList.add(listObject);
        }
    }
}


void groupObjects() {

    object.getList().parallelStream()
            .filter(listObject-> MyEnum.STATUS.equals(listObject.getStatus()))
            .forEach(listObject-> otherList.add(listObject));
    object.getList().parallelStream()
            .filter(listObject-> !MyEnum.STATUS.equals(listObject.getStatus()))
            .forEach(listObject-> someOtherList.add(listObject));
}
```

And questions that raised in my head:

1. Are these ANY close to being a correct, nice, following-good-practices solution?
2. Is this good use for lambda? Any idea how to make it even simpler?
3. Maybe I should consider other classes or methods for this task?

I read already about the `.parallelStream()` part, so don't mind that for now.

Comment: A ternary expression `(MyEnum.STATUS == object.getStatus) ? otherList : someOtherList` might be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `partitioningBy`

```
Map<Boolean, List<SomeClass>> partitioned = object.getList().stream()
    .collect(partitioningBy(listObject->MyEnum.STATUS.equals(listObject.getStatus()))
```

Where `partitioned.get(true)` will give you a list with the objects that had the status `MyEnum.STATUS` and `partitioned.get(false)` will get you the objects that didn't.

Comment: Where is partitioningBy() defined?  Is that a static import?

Comment: Static import from `java.util.stream.Collectors`.